# Value of vuex getter not updating when switching between routed components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex getter that takes the value of an array from my state.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tableRow: [
            {
                "name": 1,
                "numSongs": 2,
                "Year": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    getters:{
        tRow : state => {
            return state.tableRow
        }
    }
});
```

I have a function that takes the values from a table row and sets the value of it to my computed property for the getter.

```
       $("#table1 tr").click(function () {
            var list = [];

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
                $tds = $row.find("td");

            list.push({ name: $tds.eq(0).text(), numSongs: $tds.eq(1).text(), Year: $tds.eq(2).text() });
            // self.$store.state.tableRow = list;
            this.tabRow = list;
            console.log(this.tabRow);
             self.passData();
        });
    });
},

computed: {
    tabRow(){
     return this.$store.getters.tRow;
    }
},
```

Then in another one of my routed components i set the same computed property and then try to call it in the template but the value it outputs is the default values i gave it.

```
mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log(this.tabRow)
    // self.passedRow = self.$store.state.tableRow;
    self.passedRow = this.tabRow;
    this.startDoughnut(this.$refs.canvas, 'Doughnut');
},
    computed: {
    tabRow(){
     return this.$store.getters.tRow;
    }
```

I am not properly efficient with vuex yet so i am not sure why this won't work any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this *this.tabRow = list;* what you mean by setting the value?

Comment: yes this.tabRow =list is how i update tabrows value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is not possible in vue compute property and also in Vuex. Computed properties and vuex getters areread only.

```
 this.tabRow = list;
======================
 computed: {
    tabRow(){
     return this.$store.getters.tRow;
    }
```

Do this

```
computed: {
  tabRow(){
    get: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.tRow;
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
      commit('SET_TABLEROW', newValue)
    });
    }
   }
```

In store add a mutation

```
 mutations:{
        SET_TABLEROW: (state,list) => {
            state.tableRow=list
        }
    }
```

refer https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

Comment: Great . That will guide you :)

Answer (score 1):

`I have a function that takes the values from a table row and sets the value of it to my computed property for the getter.`
Examining your second block of code:

You are trying to set the value of `list` to the computed property `tabRow`. [Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) are by default getter-only, i.e we can only get or acess a value not set a value.

As far as I understood your problem you want to take the value from the table row and add it to the `tableRow` property in your vuex state. For that you need a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html)

```
$("#table1 tr").click(function () {
            
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
    $tds = $row.find("td");

    var list = { name: $tds.eq(0).text(), numSongs: $tds.eq(1).text(), Year: $tds.eq(2).text() };
    self.$store.commit('addTableRow', list);
    self.passData();
});
```

In you vuex store add the mutation

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tableRow: [
            {
                "name": 1,
                "numSongs": 2,
                "Year": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    getters:{
        tRow : state => {
            return state.tableRow
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        addTableRow: (state, list) => {
            state.tableRow.push(list);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DanielM96 well it is dev who is first to answer, kudos to him